# How can I trigger an a KeyEvent in an EventHandler? (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

Let's say I have an `EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEvent = event -> {...};`

How would I invoke the event? `fireEvent()` takes an `Event` and I tried to cast to an `Event` like `fireEvent((Event) keyEvent);` but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Why don't you just define a method containing the code in the event handler and invoke it directly?

Comment: Isn't the only function in the EventHandler handle?

Comment: Well you're using a lambda expression, so that method doesn't even have a name. I meant, define another method and invoke it from the handler, and also invoke it whenever you need from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your handler doesn't use the event, then you can just do

```
keyEvent.handle(null);
```

to invoke it.

If it does, I would just factor it to another method taking the information you need as a parameter. E.g. if you only need the `KeyCode` you could do:

```
private void processKeyPress(KeyCode code) {
    // ...
}
```

then your event handler would be:

```
// surely keyEventHandler (or similar) is a better name than keyEvent:
EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler = e -> processKeyPress(e.getCode());
```

Now you can just invoke the `processKeyPress` method when you need it, e.g.

```
processKeyPress(KeyCode.ENTER);
```

Here's a simple example that uses the character from a key typed event. Note how both the action event handler on the button, and the key typed handler on the scene invoke the `processKey` method:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NumberPad extends Application {

    private final ObjectProperty<Number> value = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Integer(0));

    private final StringProperty trailingZeros = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    private boolean decimalPressed = false ;
    private int numDecimalPlaces = 0 ;

    private final Label display = new Label();


    private void processKey(char c) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            int val = c - '0' ;
            if (decimalPressed) {
                if (val == 0 && numDecimalPlaces > 0) {
                    trailingZeros.set(trailingZeros.get()+"0");
                } else {
                    trailingZeros.set("");
                }
                numDecimalPlaces++ ;
                value.set(new Double(value.get().doubleValue() + val * Math.pow(10, -numDecimalPlaces)));
            } else {
                value.set(new Integer(value.get().intValue() * 10 + val));
            }
        } else if (c == '.') {
            decimalPressed = true ;
        } else if (c == 'C') {
            value.set(new Integer(0));
            decimalPressed = false ;
            numDecimalPlaces = 0 ;
            trailingZeros.set("");
        }
    }

    private Button createButton(char c) {
        Button button = new Button(Character.toString(c));

        button.setOnAction(e -> processKey(c));

        button.setFont(Font.font(24));
        button.setMinSize(25, 25);
        button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        GridPane.setFillHeight(button, true);
        GridPane.setFillWidth(button, true);
        return button ;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        display.setFont(Font.font(24));
        display.textProperty().bind(value.asString().concat(trailingZeros));

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setHgap(5);
        root.setVgap(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        root.add(display, 0, 0, 3, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setOnKeyTyped(e -> processKey(e.getCharacter().charAt(0)));

        for (int value = 0 ; value <= 9; value++) {
            char c = (char)('0' + value) ;

            Button button = createButton(c);

            if (value == 0) {
                root.add(button, 0, 3);
            } else {
                int row = 3 - (value - 1) / 3 ;
                int col = (value - 1) % 3 ;
                root.add(button,  col, row);
            }

        }

        root.add(createButton('.'), 1, 4);
        root.add(createButton('C'),  2,  4);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```